# Nginx not sending gzipped assets when passing trough a load balancer

Tags: nginx, proxy, load-balancing, gzip

I have a nginx server acting as load balancer, which delegates requests to other application servers.

When I try to request a asset directly to the application server, the asset is served in it's gzipped version, sample:

`➜  ~ curl -IH 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' http://application/asset.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2016 14:13:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 35038
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Cache-Control: public`

While the same request to the load balancer, returns the non-compressed version of the asset.

`➜  ~ curl -IH 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' https://load-balancer/asset.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2016 14:16:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 240442
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Cache-Control: public
Accept-Ranges: bytes`

Here my configuration for the LB:

    `location / {
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; # if use ssl
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://application;
    }`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved!**

I figured out myself that the request sent from the load balancer to the upstream (application server), is done in HTTP/1.0, while the nginx server in the application side, only compressed the files when the request was in HTTP >= 1.1, due to default params.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_http_version

Comment: Perhaps you could share how you solved this issue, rather than just what it is, and accept your own answer.

Comment: I think the answer, with the link above self explains how to solve the problem :) 
Solution for lazy minds: just configure the parameter gzip_http_version, which defines the minimum HTTP version to compress assets with.

Comment: Great :) Once you can, please mark your answer as accepted, though I think new users have to wait a bit before they can do that.

Answer (score 4):

There is another way to solve this. You can set a higher HTTP protocol version for proxying connections to upstream. It can be done by this parameter: `proxy_http_version 1.1;`

It would be a better choice because this way you can benefit from lots of HTTP/1.1 advantages like ***persistent connections*** and ***Extra new status codes***.

For example this is my own settings block:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.tld;
    location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_pass http://my-up-stream;
    }
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version

Comment: The proxy_http_version 1.1 also solved the gzip_static issue after proxy_pass, thanks!